# jmagick: new ImageInfo fails on exported jar

Tags: java, imagemagick, jmagick

Im using JMagick 6.3.9 for resizing and cropping images. When I run the program from within Eclipse it runs fine no problem.
However, when I export into a jar file and try running the jar file the program just does not continue when it reaches  `ImageInfo info = new ImageInfo(targetFile);` 
I get no error messages, no exceptions, no load on the cpu. Nothing.

Any ideas what the issue might be? This happens on both windows and linux (windows being the computer used for developing)

**EDIT**: There seems to be an issue with finding the dll/so file.
I removed the dll from its usual directory. When I execute from within eclipse, I get the same behavior of the program simply refusing to continue without any exceptions etc.

It seems the exported program cannot find the dll in the directory that was specified in the path variable. Am I missing something?

Comment: Where are your images? Are they getting loaded on startup or you are loading them after startup?

Comment: The images are being downloaded by the program. I.e.: Images are downloaded to a specific directory and then the downloaded images are getting resized.
There shouldnt be a difference in that regard between executing the program directly in eclipse or by executing the exported jar file.